# Is String.intern() thread safe

Tags: java, string, thread-safety

I would like to use String.intern() in Java to save memory (use the internal pool for strings with the same content). I call this method from different threads. Is it a problem?

Comment: Would be very surprised if it isn't threadsafe. That'd be a major flaw in that library design.

Comment: Where do those strings come from?

Comment: @jlordo - Any string expression that is not a compile-time constant is not automatically interned. So, for instance, `new String("abc") != "abc"`; however, `"ab" + "c" == "abc"` (because of interning).

Comment: Its a native method, so you would have to look in the source code to be absolutely sure, but I would be seriously surprised if it isn't.

Comment: @TedHopp: I am aware of that. Still, we don't know where the strings in OPs code come from.

Comment: @jlordo - Why would it matter?

Answer (score 5):

The short answer to your question is yes. It's thread-safe.

However, you might want to reconsider using this facility to reduce memory consumption. The reason is that you are unable to remove any entires from the list of interned strings. A better solution would be to create your own facility for this. All you'd need is to store your strings in a `HashMap<String,String>` like so:

```
public String getInternedString(String s) {
    synchronized(strings) {
        String found = strings.get(s);
        if(found == null) {
            strings.put(s, s);
            found = s;
        }
        return found;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could also mention the dreadful `intern` performance. If I remember correctly, the time complexity is O(*n*) where *n* is the current size of the string pool.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `if (found == null)`? Also, as written, this is hardly thread safe, even if `strings` is a thread-safe data structure.

Comment: Simpler to use a ConcurrentHashMap than worry about locking yourself

Comment: I originally didn't have any `synchronized` block in there, since there are more than one way to express that. That was clearly the wrong choice and I have edited it to include it.

Comment: @Bohemian: or use a Guava [`Interner`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Interners.html).

Comment: @EliasMårtenson You just claim that it is thread-save, without any reasoning. How is this answering the question? Please follow-up.

Comment: The virtual machine specification contains the following sentence: *Thus, the following expression must have the value true:*
`("a" + "b" + "c").intern() == "abc"`. This sentence can not be true unless `.intern()` is thread-safe.

Comment: The performance penalty of String.intern() is not that bad after the improvements made in java7+. See http://java-performance.info/string-intern-in-java-6-7-8/

Answer (score 3):

- As an immutable Java-String is returned, the method is thread-safe. You cannot manipulate the String as-is.
- The documentation really suggests that it *is* thread-safe. (by emphasizing *for any*)

> It follows that *for any* two strings s and t, s.intern() == t.intern()
>   is true if and only if s.equals(t) is true.

- Thirdly, the JNI-interface uses C-language `jobject`s. `jstring` is one of them and is as all `jobject`s immutable by definition. Thus, also on a native c-level we preserve thread-safety.

Naming these, we have good reasons to say it's thread-safe.

**PS:** However, you could end up in challenging results if you use multiple class loaders, because the String-pool is maintained per `String-class`.

```
A pool of strings, initially empty, is maintained privately by the class String.
```

Comment: `java.lang.String` can only be loaded by the bootstrap class loader.

Comment: @irreputable I'm not sure on how you would do it, but if one does it might matter.