# String.intern() thread safety guaranteed?

Tags: java, string, multithreading

Is there any documented guarantee that `String.intern()` is thread safe?  The javadoc alludes to it but does not address it directly:

> Returns a canonical representation for the string object. A pool of
>   strings, initially empty, is maintained privately by the class String.
>
> When the intern method is invoked, if the pool already contains a
>   string equal to this String object as determined by the equals(Object)
>   method, then the string from the pool is returned. Otherwise, this
>   String object is added to the pool and a reference to this String
>   object is returned.
>
> It follows that for any two strings s and t, s.intern() == t.intern()
>   is true if and only if s.equals(t) is true.
>
> All literal strings and string-valued constant expressions are
>   interned. String literals are defined in section 3.10.5 of the The
>   Java™ Language Specification.

Notably, the javadoc says that a String from the pool is guaranteed to be returned, but not that the pool itself is thread safe (so as written it appears to leave the door open for a pool entry to be replaced in the event of competing threads, although I think this interpretation is unlikely).

And the JDK source of `String` shows `intern()` to be a native method which does not shed any light on its thread safety:

```
public native String intern();
```

My concern is specifically related to whether the following would be fully thread safe, guaranteeing only one `MyObject` is **created** (not merely stored in the cache) for each unique string value in the face of concurrent requests:

```
public void myMethod(String myString)
{
    // Get object from cache, the cache itself is thread safe
    MyObject object = myCache.get(myString);
    if (object == null)
    {
        synchronized(myString.intern())
        {
            // Retry cache to avoid race condition
            object = myCache.get(myString);
            if (object == null)
            {
                object = new MyObject(myString);
                // ... do some startup / config of the object ...
                myCache.put(object);
            }
        }
    }
    // do something useful with the object
}
```

I wish to avoid synchronizing on either the method or the cache itself since the creation of the object can take some time (entails network access).  There are workarounds such as maintaining a local thread safe cache / pool of strings but it is not worth doing unless necessary.  The memory implications of `String.intern()` (inability to remove interned strings from the cache) are not relevant for this particular use case (small number of strings being used).

I believe that `String.intern()` is thread safe and that the code above is fine, but the lack of direct confirmation from a reputable source leaves me slightly concerned.

This question has been asked here multiple times before, but no concrete answer with references has been provided:

- [Is String.Intern() thread safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14798003/is-string-intern-thread-safe)
- [How do intern'd strings behave between different threads and classloaders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294134/how-do-internd-strings-behave-between-different-threads-and-classloarders)

Comment: Why use `String.intern()` at all? Why synchronize on a `String` at all for that matter?

Comment: Also, if you are looking for a thread-safe, concurrent-friendly cache implementation, use Guava's LoadingCache

Comment: @fge To guarantee only one object for the specific string is constructed and cached.  Imagine the strings are paths to resources for which only one object can be created.  The cache here is merely a synchronized or concurrent HashMap.

Comment: That actually sounds like you might want a Guava [`Striped<Lock>`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Striped.html), which maps objects to locks in a hashed way.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Good find, that is essentially what I need to accomplish, but if String.intern() is thread safe then it saves me an import and a little bit of complexity for this particular case.

Comment: It might save you a little bit of complexity, but the awkwardness cost seems high.  In particular, it makes your code incompatible in _interesting_ and hard-to-debug ways with any _other_ code that tries to synchronize on strings.  Maybe they're using the constant string "foo" as a global lock, and you happen to get a resource path named "foo", and then you get [nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).  It may look like you're saving complexity, but I'd still call this a fragile hack.

Comment: @LouisWasserman That is a really good point...  Please consider adding it as an answer so that I can accept it (even if it does not directly answer the asked question).

Comment: @LouisWasserman Merely in defence of my solution, I would note that these particular strings will not be used elsewhere (they are unique path identifiers for locks for leadership election).  However, your point stands and so as a mater of general good practice I will avoid such locking (thanks!).

Comment: To my knowledge, `intern` is thread-safe.  At least that's the way we implemented it on iSeries (and there would have been far fewer hoops to jump through had there been no thread safety requirement).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That actually sounds like you might want a Guava [`Striped<Lock>`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Striped.html), which maps objects to locks in a hashed way.  Synchronizing on interned strings seems like a potentially dangerous hack that could have [weird side effects](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html) if any other code you're using had the same idea.